# Shiny self-adjusting icon images

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have a shiny app in which I want to have action buttons with images. Below is a sample code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

url = "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/button_play_89677.jpg"

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    box(width = 12,
        column(
          3, actionBttn(
            "button1", label = "figure 1",
            icon = div(img(src = url)),
            block = FALSE,
            style = "fill"
          )),
        column(
          3, actionBttn(
            "button2", label = "figure 2",
            icon = div(img(src = url)),
            style = "fill"
          )),
        column(
          3, actionBttn(
            "button3", label = "figure 3",
            icon = div(img(src = url)),
            style = "fill"
          )),
        column(
          3, actionBttn(
            "button4", label = "figure 4",
            icon = div(img(src = url)),
            style = "fill"
          ))
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$action = renderText('abc')
}

app = shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app)
```

This will cause a problem that **if the browser is not maximized, the images will overlap and won't show entirely**. Is there a way to tell shiny to dodge the images and show each image entirely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not certain if this is what you want, but you can try ```img(src = url, width = "100%")``` for each icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems not bad like this:

```
icon = div(
  style = "width: 100%; height: 100%", 
  img(src = url, style = "width: inherit; height: inherit;")
)
```

Comment: This is not what I am expecting originally, but it definitely works for me! Thank you so much!